# Can we have a guideline about astrology for the on-topic section in the help center?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, new-users

As it stands now, the [Help Center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for on-topic questions does not mention anything about questions about astrology, which is off-topic such as [this recent question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/49021/31410) (which might get deleted soon by the roomba). Can we have another guideline about astrology-related questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I adapted the text from our [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and added it to the [Help Center](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **What questions are off topic here?**
>
> [...]
>
> Questions which require answers from astrology (e.g. horoscopes). However, you may ask questions that are motivated by astrological sources but concern only astronomical phenomena. Also, we have allowed questions about devices (such as symbols) that are in use in astronomy where the answer lies in the history of astrology.

Comment: great, thanks! ...and a few more characters...

Comment: Can we have a "community specific reason" closing comments for astrology questions just like we have for Earth Science type of question? Maybe something like "question related to astrology are off-topic ...."?

Comment: @NilayGhosh That's possible, yes. We have limited slots for those (2 of 3 remaining) so you'd need to make that a separate meta question for people to vote on.

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks. I have asked: https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/845/should-we-have-a-community-specific-closing-reason-for-astrology-questions