# Should we have a community-specific closing reason for Astrology questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Previous discussions:

- [Should we add non-physical and/or astrology questions to the off-topic list?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/should-we-add-non-physical-and-or-astrology-questions-to-the-off-topic-list/151)
- [Can we consider Indian Astrology as astronomy?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/536/can-we-consider-indian-astrology-as-astronomy/538)
- [Can we have a guideline about astrology for the on-topic section in the help center?](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/can-we-have-a-guideline-about-astrology-for-the-on-topic-section-in-the-help-cen)

Point is astrology questions are off-topic. So, shouldn't we have a community-specific closing reason just like we have for Earth-Science questions instead of mentioning that "this question is off-topic as it doesn't appear to be scope of this site"?

<sub>*called2voyage motivated me to ask this as a separate question based on the recent discussion involving astrology questions</sub>

Comment: Ok, the close reason in my answer below is now active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a good idea. Here's my suggestion of close reason text, adapted from the Help Center text:

> Questions which require answers from astrology (e.g. horoscopes) are off-topic, unless they concern devices (such as symbols) that are in use in astronomy where the answer lies in the history of astrology. For more information, see the [meta discussion](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/can-we-have-a-guideline-about-astrology-for-the-on-topic-section-in-the-help-cen).